# Separating file extensions using python os.path module

Tags: python

I'm working in python with `os.path.splitext()` and curious if it is possible to separate filenames from extensions with multiple "."?  e.g.  "foobar.aux.xml" using splitext. Filenames vary from [foobar, foobar.xml, foobar.aux.xml].  Is there a better way?

Comment: @Nick, not quite. He wants to handle filenames with multiple extensions.

Comment: `os.path.splitext()` will correctly split `"foobar.aux.xml"` into `"foobar.aux"` and `".xml"`. Do you want/need something else?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Split with `os.extsep`.

```
>>> import os
>>> 'filename.ext1.ext2'.split(os.extsep)
['filename', 'ext1', 'ext2']
```

If you want everything after the first dot:

```
>>> 'filename.ext1.ext2'.split(os.extsep, 1)
['filename', 'ext1.ext2']
```

If you are using paths with directories that may contain dots:

```
>>> def my_splitext(path):
...     """splitext for paths with directories that may contain dots."""
...     li = []
...     path_without_extensions = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), os.path.basename(path).split(os.extsep)[0])
...     extensions = os.path.basename(path).split(os.extsep)[1:]
...     li.append(path_without_extensions)
...     # li.append(extensions) if you want extensions in another list inside the list that is returned.
...     li.extend(extensions)
...     return li
... 
>>> my_splitext('/path.with/dots./filename.ext1.ext2')
['/path.with/dots./filename', 'ext1', 'ext2']
```

Comment: Or `os.path.extsep` if that happens to be convenient.

Comment: @Artur Gaspar: is this doable without knowing the exact string?  So you could separate all files in a directory or with a wildcard?

Comment: @KennyC It should work for all filenames without the complete path (filename only). The my_splitext function I added to the answer should work with all paths. If you want wildcards you should use the `glob` module.

Comment: @Artur Gaspar: thank-you.  I think I miscommunicated though.  I have hundreds of files, so using the filename for each is not possible.  Using a directory name is ideal.

Comment: @KennyC `print([my_splitext(path) for path in glob.glob('/your/path/*/wi?th/[wildcards]/*')])`

Comment: And remember that `my_splitext('somefile.1.2.3.tar.gz')` returns `['somefile', '1', '2', '3', 'tar', 'gz']`, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 7):

you could try with:

```
names = pathname.split('.')
filename = names[0]
extensions = names[1:]
```

if you want to use splitext, you can use something like:

```
import os

path = 'filename.es.txt'

while True:
    path, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
    if not ext:
        print path
        break
    else:
        print ext
```

produces:

```
.txt
.es
filename
```

Answer (score 2):

From the help of the function:

> Extension is everything from the last
>   dot to the end, ignoring leading dots.

So the answer is no, you can't do it with this function.

Comment: But it actually does not work that way. splitext will improperly split filenames with more than one dot. 
https://bugs.python.org/issue34931

Comment: As you can read on the issue, not everybody agrees this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split off any number of extensions at the end, you can create a function like this:

```
def splitext_recurse(p):
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(p)
    if ext == '':
        return (base,)
    else:
        return splitext_recurse(base) + (ext,)
```

and use it like so:

```
>>> splitext_recurse("foobar.aux.xml")
('foobar', '.aux', '.xml')
```

Comment: The process is about the same if you just want one long extension, like `('foobar', '.aux.xml')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
#Returns the file extension or empty string if none is found.
#The actual extension is the string after the last dot (if multiple).
def get_extension(filename):
    result = ""
    if "." in filename:
        result = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, this issue has been identified as a bug in Python. See https://bugs.python.org/issue34931

For example, the library os.path.splitext("St. Thomas.txt") will return:
('St. Thomas', '.txt') which is right. But os.path.splitext("St. Thomas")
returns ('St', '. Thomas'). The function below will correctly return
('St. Thomas', ''). This is the type of error we were trying to avoid.
The os.path.splitext() also strangely splits ("....txt") to ('....txt', '')
while our safe_splitext() will correctly split to ('...', '.txt')

For the original question, you can just add the expected double extensions to the list.

Because I encounter file names that may have periods embedded in the file names (and may or may not have extensions), I have reluctantly introduced the implementation below which requires explicit listing of expected extensions. In our case, we know mostly what extensions we are working with. If no extension is found, it attempts to find an unlisted extension and split that way and then emit a message to allow new extensions to be added.

```
def safe_splitext(filepath):
    """ the library os.path.splitext(path)
        can be fooled by periods in the name.
        This function is limited to the extensions we normally work with.
    """
    
    match = re.search(r'(\.pbm|\.csv|\.jpeg|\.jpg|\.json|\.lst|\.odt|'
                       r'\.pdf|\.png|\.tif|\.txt|\.xlsx|\.zip|\.html|'
                       r'\.htm|\.md|\.sha|\.DVD|\.db|\.yml|\.yaml|\.lock)$', 
                    filepath, flags=re.I)
    if bool(match):
        extension = match[1]
        name = re.sub(fr'\{extension}$', '', filepath)
        return name, extension
    
    match = re.search(r'(\.[^\.]{1,4})$', filepath, flags=re.I)
    if bool(match):
        extension = match[1]
        name = re.sub(fr'\{extension}$', '', filepath)
        print(f"Warning: unusual extension: {extension}")
        return name, extension
    
    return filepath, ''
```